# Android Remove selection EditText after long click

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, onlongclicklistener

I've got a `EditText` which I want to use in two ways

- When clicked everything is selected and the user can change the
  input.
- When long clicked the text color changes and for the rest
  nothing happens for the user.

I've tried to clear its focus, but everytime I let go after a long click everything is selected. Probably because of the `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` in the XML file. But I do want everything selected when the user just touches the ET, but not after a long press.

The code that I've got so far is:

main.java

```
ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.someET);
ET.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
ET.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());
ET.setOnLongClickListener(new myLongClickListener());

class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        v.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}

class MyLongClickListener implements OnLongClickListener{

private boolean locked = false;

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    if(locked){
        ((EditText)view).setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    } else {
        ((EditText)view).setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
    }
    locked =! locked;
    return true;
}
```

}

The DoneOnEditorActionListener is there when the user presses the enter/done button the ET will lose focus and the keyboard will hide.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` in the XML file, you may be better off controlling the selection programmatically, as needed (in whichever listeners you want):

```
myEditText.selectAll();
```

To remove the selection:

```
Selection.removeSelection(myEditText.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, probably it is caused by `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`. You can try to remove this and implement the onClick method, where you should select all the text and display the keyboard. Otherwise you should try to clear the focus from the edittext (with `clearFocus()`), and give it to another View (with `requestFocus()`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. But I know, how to hide with and without empty space:

ED.setVisibility(8) - this is 'remove' (but you can not add this ED to other view)
ED.setVisibility(4) - this is hide (you have empty space)
ED.setVisibility(0) - default, this is showing view